# How to get response data outside promise chain of Fetch?

Tags: react-native, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm using fetchApi to get data from my API.
In my RequestHelpers.js, I do this code

```js
module.exports = {
    fetchQuizCollection(){
      return fetch(HOST+API_KEY)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          let gameData = responseData
          console.log(responseData) //It work
          return responseData
        })
      .done();
    }
}
```

And I call that function in another file, I couldn't get my responseData

```
    let sampleQuiz = RequestHelpers.fetchQuizCollection()
    console.log(sampleQuiz) //undefined
```

is there any way to get data outside the promise ?

Answer (score 5):

You are treating asynchronous code as if it's synchronous. The `fetchQuizCollection()` is asynchronous, thus the data it returns isn't available when your logging code runs. You will have to wait until all the `.fetch()` functions have completed.

Just let `fetchQuizCollection()` return a promise by adding another `return` as below

```
return fetchQuizCollection(){
  return fetch(HOST+API_KEY)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    ...
```

and you can access the `sampleQuiz` in a `.then()` function.

```
let sampleQuiz = RequestHelpers.fetchQuizCollection()
    .then((sampleQuiz) => {
        console.log(sampleQuiz);
    });
```